# Back to top link on php included footer?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a footer section on my website where I want to include a back to Top link.
Problem is that it can't detect on which page of the site the user is so it sends it in the index html top. Is there any way to achieve this?

I can't use `<a href="#">Back to top</a>` since I have a base href that links to the index page of the website.

This code worked well, cross browser too:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.window.scrollTo(0,0);">TOP</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need php for this.
Just add a link like this:

```
<a href="#">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can't use that since I am using a base href that links to the index of my website.

Answer (score 7):

Add a named anchor in your page just before the content, to specify the top of your current page. Like:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<!-- Rest of your content here -->
```

Then in your footer, link to the anchor with:

```
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: I already created all the pages and although it wouldn't be hard to do so I would prefer an easier way, with a simple code in the footer section.

Comment: Alternatively you can use inline javascript: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.scrollTop(0)">Back to top</a>`

Comment: Yes but since I got a base href on all my pages, `<a href="#">` redirects to the index. How to fix that?

Comment: That's it, thanks! Although I had to change `scrollTop(0)` with just `scroll(0)`. Any idea why it's not working on latest Firefox & Opera?

Comment: This one worked on every browser: `onclick="parent.window.scrollTo(0,0);"`